# How can you grab the request object from the app object in express?

Tags: node.js, express

In express you call `var app = module.exports = express.createServer();` which creates a new `HTTPServer` object. I'd like to get access to the current `req` object from this `app`(`HTTPServer`) object. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: [Yes, there is.](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#passing-route+control) The `req` is in scope within routing callbacks. How are you trying to do it?

Comment: @MattBall Well I've bound an object to the session object of the request object (the id of the current user), and I'd like to access that in the websockets part of my app, where all I seem to have is the `app` object. Therefore, I'd like to access the request object from this HTTPServer object.

Comment: @MattBall Right, but since I need this in the websockets part of my app, I am not calling any routes. (I start up the socket.io websockets server for all paths)

Comment: There's no such thing as a `request` outside of a route--the definition of a request is "the thing that triggered this route," and there is one for each... well, request, that comes in.

Comment: @BrandonTilley But what about a websockets request with socket.io? It doesn't have a specified route but it still consists of a request to your app.

Comment: Yes, but Express doesn't handle it, the Socket.IO module (which plugs into Express somewhere) handles it. You can get cookies, etc. which are sent with the websocket request, but it's not a traditional request (and even then `request` only refers to the initial connection, so fetching it from the app object still doesn't make sense).

Answer (score 6):

The `req` object is only created when the underlying `HTTPServer` actually gets a request, and only lasts for as long as the request is processed. So it's not really meaningful to talk about it outside the context of a callback.

During a callback, you can simply copy the appropriate data from the session object somewhere else and use that copy in your websockets code. But you can't count on the request object, or even the session object, remaining after you've finished processing the request.

Showing a small code example would be helpful; it sounds like you've got an "XY problem" (you want to accomplish a goal X and you've decided that technique Y is the right way to do it, when in fact technique Z might work better).

Comment: Upvoted for "XY problem" anagoly. I didn't know about it :)